# HTTP Error 403: Forbidden w/ User Agents Added

Tags: python, http, web, web-scraping, http-status-code-403

Usually I've been able to get around 403 Errors once I've added a known User Agent but I'm now trying to login and then eventually scrape and cannot figure out how to bypass this error.

**Code:**

```
import urllib
import http.cookiejar

cj = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
authentication_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/'
payload = {
    'session_key': 'email',
    'session_password': 'password'
}
data = urllib.parse.urlencode(payload)
binary_data = data.encode('UTF-8')
req = urllib.request.Request(authentication_url, binary_data)
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
contents = resp.read()
```

**Traceback**:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/loginLinked.py", line 16, in <module>
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 161, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 469, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 579, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 507, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 441, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 587, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Comment: scraping linkedin profiles is against its [user agreement](https://www.linkedin.com/legal/user-agreement#dispute-resolution) and can/will get your account terminated. That said, many login forms contain other (hidden) input fields that also need to be sent.

Comment: To cut the long story short: they don't want you to do that. It's forbidden, so the error message is most accurate. Use the Linkedin API instead.

Comment: Unfortunately their API doesn't allow you to grab all the members in a group or do anything outside your profile which renders it mostly useless

Comment: Looks similar to [urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303449/urllib2-httperror-http-error-403-forbidden/46213623#46213623)

Answer (score 1):

See my answer to this question:

[why isn't Requests not signing into a website correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23324284/why-isnt-requests-not-signing-into-a-website-correctly/23324391#23324391)

> *I should start with stating that you really should use their API:
>   http://developer.linkedin.com/apis*
>
> There does not seem to be any POST login on the frontpage of linkedin using those parameters?
>
> This is the login URL you must POST to:
>   https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login-submit
>
> Be aware that this probably wont work either, as you need at least the csrfToken parameter from the login form.
>
> You probably need the loginCsrfParam too, also from the login form on the frontpage.
>
> Something like this might work. Not tested, you might need to add the other POST parameters.

```
import requests
s = requests.session()

def get_csrf_tokens():
    url = "https://www.linkedin.com/"
    req = s.get(url).text

    csrf_token = req.split('name="csrfToken" value=')[1].split('" id="')[0]
    login_csrf_token = req.split('name="loginCsrfParam" value="')[1].split('" id="')[0]

    return csrf_token, login_csrf_token


def login(username, password):
    url = "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login-submit"
    csrfToken, loginCsrfParam = get_csrf_tokens()

    data = {
        'session_key': username,
        'session_password': password,
        'csrfToken': csrfToken,
        'loginCsrfParam': loginCsrfParams
    }

    req = s.post(url, data=data)

login('username', 'password')
```